# Can I insert data to my DB from a script outside my document root?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if this can be done, and by the lack of info I've found, if I would even want to do it..., but, I have a script that sits outside my document root folder that i post data to from an email using a php pipe.  The script works just fine, but When I try to connect to a database that is inside my document root, I can't insert data to it.  Is this possible, or do I need to move the file  into the same directory.. right now I'm trying to access my connect file like this...

```
require_once('/home2/username/public_html/dir/connect/conn_to_db.php');
```

or this, as the file sites in my username dir..

```
require_once('public_html/dir/connect/conn_to_db.php');
```

Any chance this can be done? thanks

Comment: If the `path/to/conn_to_db.php` is correct , I don't see any problem unless the user running the script does not have permission to the `path/to/conn_to_db.php` . However you could just copy the connection parameters to your script and connect to the database from within the script to see if it works .

Comment: Thanks for the reply... It actually does work... after some nasty debugging I found out that when I read the header email it gives me this.. FirstName LastName <theemail@emai.com>  When I need only the email... Too tired, too late!  Thanks anyway